# configurate netbeans to remember my cursor position

Tags: php, netbeans

how to configure netbeans so when i start open my previous work, it will put cursor into  line number i have left them before. is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have downloaded Netbeans hibernate plugin and it works like a charm.

Comment: Sorry, can't find it. Can you show me it, please? And how to configure it to remember cursor position. Thank you!